# oracle sql return count along with other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

This question is about oracle 12.1.0.2 on aix 7.2.

I have 5 tables and I want to do this query:

```
select owner, table_name, LAST_DDL_TIME, count(*) 
from dba_objects
where owner = 'WAREHOUSE' 
and OBJECT_NAME in ('table1','table2','table3','table4','table5') 
and OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
```

I want the 3 columns in the select clause and the actual count of the 5 tables.  I want to do this in one query if possible.

If I add group by owner, table_name, LAST_DDL_TIME it will return a count of 1 for each row.

So my result set I want will look like this:

```
OWNER       OBJECT_NAME     LAST_DDL_TIME           COUNT(*)
SCHEMA1     TABLE1          7/9/2016 3:47:27 PM     5932158
SCHEMA1     TABLE2          7/9/2016 3:47:31 PM     432
SCHEMA1     TABLE3          7/9/2016 3:47:15 PM     958741
SCHEMA1     TABLE4          7/9/2016 3:47:31 PM     11298
SCHEMA1     TABLE5          7/9/2016 3:47:15 PM     3645873385
```

Comment: "actual count of 5 tables". You mean 5? Or are you looking for number of rows?

Comment: Why do you need `owner` in the output if you are filtering by `owner = 'WAREHOUSE'`? Also - you really need the current count(*) - counts as of the last time stats were gathered would not suffice?

Comment: If you just want an approximate count, you can use `dba_tab_statistics.num_rows`. If you want the exact count, you could write a SQL function to return a row count when given the owner and table_name as parameters. Then just call the SQL function in your select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some XML magic to do dynamic SQL inside plain SQL query.

```
select owner, object_name, LAST_DDL_TIME, 
       to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from "'||owner||'"."'||object_name||'"')),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count
from dba_objects
where owner = 'WAREHOUSE' 
and OBJECT_NAME in ('table1','table2','table3','table4','table5') 
and OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
```